# animation: fill after delay

Tags: css, animation, svg

I have this SVG logo with stroke and fill animation, but i need to trigger the fill after the 4th second so it doesn't appear with the first animation.

```
<defs>
    <style>
        .st0 {
            stroke-dasharray: 800;
            stroke-dashoffset: 0;
            -webkit-animation: dash 4s linear forwards;
            -moz-animation: dash 4s linear forwards;
            -o-animation: dash 4s linear forwards;
            animation: dash 4s linear forwards;
            animation: fill .8s eas;
            -webkit-animation: fill .8s eas;
            -moz-animation: fill .8s eas;
            -o-animation: fill .8 eas;
        }   



        @-webkit-keyframes dash {
            from {
                stroke-dashoffset: 800;
            }
            to {
                stroke-dashoffset: 0;
                fill: #000;
            }
        }

    </style>
 </defs>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`animation-delay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay) property as the fourth value in the `animation` attribute as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation)

Example:

```
.st0 {
    ....
    animation: fill .8s eas 4s;
}
```

However you might run in to problems playing two animations with your syntax, as described here: [Play multiple CSS animations at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986129/play-multiple-css-animations-at-the-same-time)

Comment: Adding the 4th value does not change it. I am thinking it may be because of the FILL:#000 in TO, by being there it will always run with the "dash" i think. But if i remove it the animation doesn't trigger at all.

Comment: Post a fiddle and I'll be able to tinker with it.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the question, then you are looking for these lines of code 
`-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;`

These will allow your animation to run and then stay with the position, size and what ever you else might be animating :)