# Expressing CSS3 @keyframes using seconds instead of percentages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I learned CSS3 `@keyframes` syntax in January 2016 and, over 2 years later, I now find myself using `@keyframes` animations in no small amount of my work (more sophisticated than CSS3 transitions, less cumbersome than javascript-based animations).

One thing I really miss though is the ability to express `@keyframes` in seconds rather than in percentages. Are there any hacks to achieve this?

I know I can use the following `100s` hack to cycle through rainbow colors, with one cycle every 3 seconds:

```css
div {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: violet;
    animation: myAnimation 100s;
}

@keyframes myAnimation {
    0% {background-color: red;}
    3% {background-color: orange;}
    6% {background-color: yellow;}
    9% {background-color: green;}
   12% {background-color: cyan;}
   15% {background-color: blue;}
   18% {background-color: violet;}
  100% {background-color: violet;}
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

But it means that the animation is still running (albeit imperceptibly) for another 82 seconds after it has (effectively) finished. Amongst other concerns, this puts multiple iterations out of reach.

What I'd really like to write is simply:

```
@keyframes myAnimation {

  0s {background-color: red;}
  3s {background-color: orange;}
  6s {background-color: yellow;}
  9s {background-color: green;}
 12s {background-color: cyan;}
 15s {background-color: blue;}
 18s {background-color: violet;}
}
```

Is there any better approach than the one I have detailed in the code box above?

---

## Example using Multiple Elements

I realise in hindsight I have probably made the example above too simple given that it involves animating a single element and my question originally emerges from wanting to animate multiple elements in sync with each other.

So, here is a slightly more elaborate example, showing a set-up much closer to the one which gave rise to my question in the first place:

```css
div {
display: inline-block;
width: 48px;
height: 48px;
margin-right: 6px;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) {
background-color: red;
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
background-color: orange;
animation: myAnimationOrange 100s;
}

div:nth-of-type(3) {
background-color: yellow;
animation: myAnimationYellow 100s;
}

div:nth-of-type(4) {
background-color: green;
animation: myAnimationGreen 100s;
}

div:nth-of-type(5) {
background-color: cyan;
animation: myAnimationCyan 100s;
}

div:nth-of-type(6) {
background-color: violet;
animation: myAnimationViolet 100s;
}

@keyframes myAnimationOrange {
    0% {background-color: white;}
    1% {background-color: white;}
    2% {background-color: orange;}
  100% {background-color: orange;}
}

@keyframes myAnimationYellow {
    0% {background-color: white;}
    2% {background-color: white;}
    3% {background-color: yellow;}
  100% {background-color: yellow;}
}

@keyframes myAnimationGreen {
    0% {background-color: white;}
    3% {background-color: white;}
    4% {background-color: green;}
  100% {background-color: green;}
}

@keyframes myAnimationCyan {
    0% {background-color: white;}
    4% {background-color: white;}
    5% {background-color: cyan;}
  100% {background-color: cyan;}
}

@keyframes myAnimationViolet {
    0% {background-color: white;}
    5% {background-color: white;}
    6% {background-color: violet;}
  100% {background-color: violet;}
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your point, with animation duration and percentages you are basically defining how many seconds will each keyframe last. If seconds notation was used, that would mean that each keframes block would have fixed duration, which is not the case with percentages.

Comment: it's like you want to limit the feature of CSS3 animation ... if we specify seconds, the timing-function and duration will be useless then

Comment: I don't understand how adding units is limiting, @Temani. I can express a `width` in `px` or in `vw` (which works differently) or in `%` (which works differently again). None of these limits the others.

Comment: @Rounin if you use px with width it means that it's static and it won't change so it's limited unlike using % with width where it's dynamic and can be responsive, etc .... same think with animation, when you specify %, you can later use this animation with any element by speficying the duration, delay and timing function so it's dynamic ... but if you set fixed second to the animation it will be static and you can no more use different duration, delay,etc since you fixed everything. So you have limited you are animation to only one use case unlike with %

Comment: @MladenIlic - yes, but let's say over a period of 20 seconds, I want 20 different things to happen. So that's a duration of `20s` and I'm using `5%`, `10%` to mark each keyframe. Now, let's say I want to add 3 more items. So I update the duration to `23s` and... now I have to go through all the percentages changing `5%` to `4.345%`, `10%` to `8.69%`, `15%` to   `13.035%` etc.

Comment: @TemaniAfif - using hard units like seconds and pixels in addition to dynamic units like percentages and viewport width units isn't limiting. Essentially, being able to use _any_ different, additional units (be they hard or dynamic) isn't limiting. You can say that hard units are more limiting than dynamic units and I would agree with you. But it's not the case that being able to use hard units as well as dynamic units is some kind of constraint.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Don't forget you can run multiple animations on the same element, and that you can set their `duration`, `delay` and all other `animation-...` rules independently.

E.g, you can split all your keyframes to single-key @keyframes rules.
Then it's easy to control when they'll  kick in and to chain them.

```css
div {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: violet;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-name: orange, yellow, green, cyan, blue, violet;
    animation-delay: 0s, 3s, 6s, 9s, 12s, 15s, 18s;
    animation-duration: 3s; /* same for all */
}

@keyframes orange {
    to { background-color: orange; }
}
@keyframes yellow {
    to { background-color: yellow; }
}
@keyframes green {
    to { background-color: green; }
}
@keyframes cyan {
    to { background-color: cyan; }
}
@keyframes blue {
    to { background-color: blue; }
}
@keyframes violet {
    to { background-color: violet; }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

### Regarding question's edit

In this case, you don't even need to combine multiple animations on the same element, but simply set the `animation-delay` accordingly:

```css
div {
 /* same for all */
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-duration: 3s;
}
div:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-name: orange;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
div:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-name: yellow;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
div:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-name: green;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
div:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-name: cyan;
  animation-delay: 9s;
}
div:nth-of-type(5) {
  animation-name: blue;
  animation-delay: 12s;
}
div:nth-of-type(6) {
  animation-name: violet;
  animation-delay: 15s;
}

@keyframes orange {
    to { background-color: orange; }
}
@keyframes yellow {
    to { background-color: yellow; }
}
@keyframes green {
    to { background-color: green; }
}
@keyframes cyan {
    to { background-color: cyan; }
}
@keyframes blue {
    to { background-color: blue; }
}
@keyframes violet {
    to { background-color: violet; }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

But if you want to combine both together, it's also all possible:

```css
div {
 /* same for all */
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-duration: 3s;
}
div:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-name: orange, yellow, green, cyan, blue, violet;
  animation-delay: 0s, 3s, 6s, 9s, 12s, 15s;
}
div:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-name: yellow, green, cyan, blue, violet;
  animation-delay: 3s, 6s, 9s, 12s, 15s;
}
div:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-name: green, cyan, blue, violet;
  animation-delay: 6s, 9s, 12s, 15s;
}
div:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-name: cyan, blue, violet;
  animation-delay: 9s, 12s, 15s;
}
div:nth-of-type(5) {
  animation-name: blue, violet;
  animation-delay: 12s, 15s;
}
div:nth-of-type(6) {
  animation-name: violet;
  animation-delay: 15s;
}

@keyframes orange {
    to { background-color: orange; }
}
@keyframes yellow {
    to { background-color: yellow; }
}
@keyframes green {
    to { background-color: green; }
}
@keyframes cyan {
    to { background-color: cyan; }
}
@keyframes blue {
    to { background-color: blue; }
}
@keyframes violet {
    to { background-color: violet; }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, @kaiido, I **really** like this. If I don't find a better solution I'll mark this as the best answer. What I'd really like to do is apply single animations on multiple elements (rather than multiple animations on a single element). I realise that the original example I gave in my question was too simple so I've updated it to better explain the issue I am encountering.

Comment: Please note this will only work if animation-iteration-count is 1 as delays are only initial offsets.

Answer (score 3):

## SCSS Mixins to convert delays to percentages

Example https://codepen.io/jakob-e/pen/vVXeOe

**SCSS**

```
body {
    @include animation-timeline {
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        
        @include tween(0s, (background-color: violet));        
        @include tween(3s, (background-color: red));
        @include tween(3s, (background-color: orange));
        @include tween(3s, (background-color: yellow));
        @include tween(3s, (background-color: green));
        @include tween(3s, (background-color: cyan));
        @include tween(3s, (background-color: blue));
        @include tween(3s, (background-color: violet));
    }
}
```

**CSS Output**

```
body {
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-name: u33q65otn;
    animation-duration: 21s;
}

@keyframes u33q65otn {
    0% { background-color: violet; }
    14.2857142857% { background-color: red; }
    28.5714285714% { background-color: orange; }
    42.8571428571% { background-color: yellow; }
    57.1428571429% { background-color: green; }
    71.4285714286% { background-color: cyan; }
    85.7142857143% { background-color: blue; }
    100% { background-color: violet; }
}
```

**The mixins**

```
//  global context flags using wierd ☠️ names to minimize 
//  chance of naming conflicts with other scss variables
$☠️--animation-timeline-duration: null;
$☠️--animation-timeline-tweens  : null;

//  mixin to create an animation context for nested tweens
//  used to calculate the total duration of the animation
//  converting each tween delay into percentages 
@mixin animation-timeline($name: unique-id()) {
    
    //  global context flag to sum up duration
    $☠️--animation-timeline-duration: 0s !global;    
    
    //  global context map to hold animation tweens
    $☠️--animation-timeline-tweens  : () !global;
    
    //  mixin content (the included tweens)
    @content;

    //  animation name and duration 
    //  note! if no name is provided a unique id will be used
    //  this allows you to create one-time-use animations without
    //  having to deal with animation naming conflicts :-)     
    animation-name:     $name;
    animation-duration: $☠️--animation-timeline-duration;

    //  create keyframes
    @keyframes #{$name} {
        //  loop through the included tweens 
        @each $time, $props in $☠️--animation-timeline-tweens {
            //  calculate percentage based on total duration
            #{percentage($time/$☠️--animation-timeline-duration)}{ 
                //  print out the tween properties
                @each $prop, $value in $props {
                    #{$prop}:$value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    //  reset global context flags
    $☠️--animation-timeline-duration: null !global;
    $☠️--animation-timeline-tweens  : null !global;
}


//  mixin to create tweens based on a delay and a map
//  containing the the tween properties*
//
//  * using a map is not optimal – but for now you are not 
//  able to save @content to variables :( 
//  
@mixin tween($delay: 0s, $props: null){
    //  only do stuff if we are in a animation-timeline context
    @if $☠️--animation-timeline-tweens {
        //  increment the total animation by the the tween delay 
        $☠️--animation-timeline-duration: $☠️--animation-timeline-duration + $delay !global;
        //  save current duration and tween props to the global tween map
        $☠️--animation-timeline-tweens: map-merge($☠️--animation-timeline-tweens,  ($☠️--animation-timeline-duration: $props)) !global;
    }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely wild mix-in that works phenomenally -- thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not at the moment. The documentation explicitly says that you can only use percentages:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

Presumably, the reason behind it is that the duration of the animation isn't defined in the keyframes but in the `animation-duration` property, so the interpolator must be able to stretch the keyframes to any duration.

Answer (score -2):

Your hack is kind of awkward. Why not just use `18s` for the animation duration, and cycle through the percentages steadily?

```css
div {
   width: 120px;
   height: 120px;
   background-color: violet;
   animation: myAnimation 18s;
}

@keyframes myAnimation {
   0% {background-color: red;}
   18% {background-color: orange;}
   37% {background-color: yellow;}
   55% {background-color: green;}
   71% {background-color: cyan;}
   88% {background-color: blue;}
   100% {background-color: violet;}
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

I don't think you're supposed to be able to use seconds for your `@keyframes` interval. We already use seconds for everything else in CSS. [See how it works here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes).

Comment: _"Why not just use 18s for the animation duration, and cycle through the percentages steadily?"_ - because it makes updating a real pain. Let's say over a period of 20 seconds, I want 20 different elements to animate. So that's a duration of 20s and I'm using 5%, 10% to mark each keyframe. Now, let's say I want to add 3 more items. So I update the duration to 23s and... now I have to go through all the percentages changing 5% to 4.345%, 10% to 8.69%, 15% to 13.035% etc.