# How can I use calculated values as keyframes?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to make my train run in a 60 minutes cycle.
Therefore, 60 Minutes are 100% of the cycle.
I want to do a calculation and use the result as a keyframe.

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 60s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes example { # 
  (1/0.6)%   {left:300px; top:0px;} # neunkirch
  (3/0.6)%   {left:200px; top:0px;} # hallau
  (4/0.6)%   {left:200px; top:0px;} # hallau
  (3/0.6)%   {left:100px; top:0px;} # trasadingen
  (4/0.6)%   {left:100px; top:0px;} # trasadingen
  (8/0.6)%   {left:0px; top:0px;} # erzingen
  (18/0.6)%   {left:0px; top:0px;} # erzingen
  (19/0.6)%   {left:100px; top:0px;} # trasadingen
  (20/0.6)%   {left:100px; top:0px;} # trasadingen
  (22/0.6)%   {left:200px; top:0px;} # hallau
  (24/0.6)%   {left:200px; top:0px;} # hallau
  (26/0.6)%   {left:300px; top:0px;} # neunkirch
  (30/0.6)%   {left:400px; top:0px;} # beringen
  (32/0.6)%   {left:500px; top:0px;} # beringerfeld
  (35/0.6)%   {left:600px; top:0px;} # neuhausen bad
  (39/0.6)%   {left:700px; top:0px;} # schaffhausen
  (49/0.6)%   {left:700px; top:0px;} # schaffhausen
  (52/0.6)%   {left:600px; top:0px;} # neuhausen bad
  (54/0.6)%   {left:500px; top:0px;} # beringerfeld
  (55/0.6)%   {left:500px; top:0px;} # beringerfeld
  (56/0.6)%   {left:400px; top:0px;} # beringen
  (57/0.6)%   {left:400px; top:0px;} # beringen
  (60/0.6)%   {left:300px; top:0px;} # neunkirch
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS Animation</h1>

<div></div>
```

PS: sorry, but I didn't manage to post the html as a html, because if I want to indent 4 spaces with shift, it will just jump to the next window on this website (the tag section).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49545440/expressing-css3-keyframes-using-seconds-instead-of-percentages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR

You can't. Use a preprocessor like `sass`. SASS is cool, CSS is not.

## The Problem

CSS works as a templating system. You can **declare a selector** which then selects an element on which you are able  **to change it's props**, right?

Yeah.. not really. You can't do whatever you like. The available selectors as of now are pretty strict in terms of dynamics. So to overcome this weakness, they introduced **variables** (below there's sample on how you'd use them).

```css
:root {
  --bgColor: #fafafa;
}

/* 
some styling
...
*/

.my-class {
  background-color: var(--bgColor);
}
```

Well.. not the solution you're looking for, because it only works on properties (eg. `background-color`, `font-size`, `width` etc.) and will be evaluated at runtime. Same goes for `calc()`.

## The Solution

Since we cannot use dynamic variables or calculated values as selectors or as part of a selector, you cannot implement this in pure CSS. However, you can use a preprocessor such as `sass` or `less` to be able to use many features including string interpolation -> `#{myCalculatedValue}%`

CSS preprocessors **transpiles the features they've provided** for you **into valid CSS** code before the browser runs it so basically **every variable** you've declared (including string interpolation, but excluding CSS vars since it wasn't provided by the preprocessor) **will be transpiled into a static value** which CSS can use (eg. `1/0.6%` will evaluate to `1.67%`). It doesn't really matter what you're doing as long as it transpiles. You can also mix the two. Example: in `sass` you can use CSS variables as well as SCSS variables.

## Requirements

This is great. We have dynamic values, we have loops, we have functions. All we need is a compiler or transpiler that turns our `scss`, `sass` or `less` code into real CSS for the browsers to be able to read it and apply.

If you're using a frontend framework (such as Angular, React or Vue), you don't have to do anything besides initializing the project with `scss` styling.

Otherwise you'll need to have something like [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) or [sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass), but you'll have to transpile it manually before you start your server.

<strike>`node-sass` is the best IMO eg. if you use server-side rendering, but there's several sass transpiler on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/).</strike>

**EDIT:** You can find several transpilers on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/).

**BONUS TIP:** If you're using VSCode, there's an extension called [Live Sass Compiler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.live-sass)(`ritwickdey.live-sass`) which, as the name suggests, will compile your `sass` files to `css` files automatically (same can be achieved with the `--watch` tag if you're using a transpiler).

Comment: I fail to see how does it affect my answer

Comment: `node-sass` is deprecated. Better to use the `sass` package you linked to instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using CSS directly, then you will have to do these calculations first and use the final values directly in your CSS.

However, if you use a CSS preprocessor such as [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/) then you can do this. For example, in Sass you can interpolate values using the syntax `#{}`:

```
@keyframes example {
    #{1/0.6}% { /* ... */ }
    #{2/0.6}% { /* ... */ }
    // ...
}
```

Using a preprocessor would also allow you to create a CSS animation using a loop, which could be pretty useful for certain animations.

Answer (score 0):

Welp, if I have to use a preprocessor, I can use python to print me CSS code just as well :/

I guess I can only automate this on a website, once I know Angular/React/Vue