# How do I get multiple css animations to play in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I'm a bit confused about how to trigger multiple animations for an element using javascript.

I'm trying to get an element (.hud) to fade-in and also bounce when clicked. Currently it will only do one or the other. The second animation class is being added to the element in a on click event. The class gets added but the animation does not play. How would I construct my code for the animation to fade-in and also bounce on click?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style> 
.anim {
  animation-name: bounceIn_1;
  animation-duration: .5s;
}

.hud {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  animation-name: fade-in;
  animation-duration: .5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0; }
  100% {
    opacity: 1; } }

@-webkit-keyframes bounceIn_1{0%,20%,40%,60%,80%,to{-webkit-animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1)}0%{opacity:0;-webkit-transform:scale3d(.3,.3,.3);transform:scale3d(.3,.3,.3)}20%{-webkit-transform:scale3d(1.1,1.1,1.1);transform:scale3d(1.1,1.1,1.1)}40%{-webkit-transform:scale3d(.9,.9,.9);transform:scale3d(.9,.9,.9)}60%{opacity:1;-webkit-transform:scale3d(1.03,1.03,1.03);transform:scale3d(1.03,1.03,1.03)}80%{-webkit-transform:scale3d(.97,.97,.97);transform:scale3d(.97,.97,.97)}to{opacity:1;-webkit-transform:scaleX(1);transform:scaleX(1)}}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>This box should fade in and bounce on click</p>

<div class="hud"></div>

<script>

element = document.querySelector('.hud');
  console.log(element);

// reset the transition by...
element.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log("clicked");
  e.preventDefault;
  element.classList.remove("anim");
  void element.offsetWidth;
  element.classList.add("anim");
}, false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Play multiple CSS animations at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986129/play-multiple-css-animations-at-the-same-time)

Comment: Not exactly. I need to play multiple animations on the same element.

Answer (score 2):

Was it so necessary for you? In order for the animation in your example to work constantly, a reset function is needed.

```js
element = document.querySelector('#red_box');
  console.log(element);

element.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault;
  console.log("clicked");
  element.classList.remove("hud");
  element.classList.remove("anim");
  void element.offsetWidth;
  element.classList.add("anim");
}, false);

/*$(".hud").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this = reset($this);
    $this.addClass("anim bounceIn_1");
    console.log("clicked");
});*/
```

```css
.anim {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  animation-name: bounceIn_1;
  animation-duration: .5s;
}

.hud {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  animation-name: fade-in;
  animation-duration: .5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0; }
  100% {
    opacity: 1; } }

@-webkit-keyframes bounceIn_1 {0%,20%,40%,60%,80%,to{-webkit-animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1)}0%{opacity:0;-webkit-transform:scale3d(.3,.3,.3);transform:scale3d(.3,.3,.3)}20%{-webkit-transform:scale3d(1.1,1.1,1.1);transform:scale3d(1.1,1.1,1.1)}40%{-webkit-transform:scale3d(.9,.9,.9);transform:scale3d(.9,.9,.9)}60%{opacity:1;-webkit-transform:scale3d(1.03,1.03,1.03);transform:scale3d(1.03,1.03,1.03)}80%{-webkit-transform:scale3d(.97,.97,.97);transform:scale3d(.97,.97,.97)}to{opacity:1;-webkit-transform:scaleX(1);transform:scaleX(1)}}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <p>This box should fade in and bounce on click</p>
  <div id="red_box" class="hud"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example Sergey. I don't think I'm getting an answer to my question. It appears you are using Jquery to create an element outside of the element. Is there a way to play multiple animations on the element with javascript?

Comment: I can redo my answer to js :)

Comment: Hi Sergey, that would be helpful. Your example works great but I'm not sure exactly how to get it to work.

Comment: @lawrencehagman, hello, i redid my answer to js. Also, add `id="red_box"` to the `div`.

Comment: did my revised answer help you?

Comment: Hi Sergey, I'm afraid it doesn't answer the original question. I need to fire "Multiple" animations. I've changed my example above to illustrate. I have to preserve the style in the .hud class and be able play another animation without removing the style in the .hud class. I'm now understanding there may not be a way to do this. I'm going to try and do it with an inline style change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219711/discussion-between-lawrencehagman-and-sergey-kuznetsov).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to put a **comma** in your `.anim` class?

`animation: bounceIn_1 .5s, fade-in .5s`

Comment: Thank you. If I set the animation property to a list of animation names, how do I trigger them independently? I will try it, seems as though the bounce would play and then the fade-in would play which is not the intent. I'm sorry, I'm confused on some of the animation basics with css.

Comment: the animation list is just for you .anim class, you could use a totally separate class, didn't you want to trigger them at the same time?

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the help. The box fades in on load, then bounces on click.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the 2 animation in the same css class and make sure that the removing and the adding of that class are done in 2 separate frames.
The first issue can be easily solved by putting a comma between the 2 animations which are now in the class .anim.
The second issue is a little bit tricky but the window.requestAnimationFrame() function will solve it !
Here you have the modified code so that you can better understand:

```js
element = document.querySelector('.hud');
  console.log(element);

// reset the transition by...
element.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log("clicked");
  e.preventDefault;
  element.classList.remove("anim");
  void element.offsetWidth;
  window.requestAnimationFrame(() => element.classList.add("anim")); /* The add() will be done before the next repaint so that we can see the change */
}, false);
```

```css
.anim {
  animation-name: fade-in, bounceIn_1;
  animation-duration: .5s;
}

.hud {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  //animation-name: fade-in; /* Remove this */
  //animation-duration: .5s; /* Remove this */
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0; }
  100% {
    opacity: 1; } }

@-webkit-keyframes bounceIn_1{0%,20%,40%,60%,80%,to{-webkit-animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1)}0%{opacity:0;-webkit-transform:scale3d(.3,.3,.3);transform:scale3d(.3,.3,.3)}20%{-webkit-transform:scale3d(1.1,1.1,1.1);transform:scale3d(1.1,1.1,1.1)}40%{-webkit-transform:scale3d(.9,.9,.9);transform:scale3d(.9,.9,.9)}60%{opacity:1;-webkit-transform:scale3d(1.03,1.03,1.03);transform:scale3d(1.03,1.03,1.03)}80%{-webkit-transform:scale3d(.97,.97,.97);transform:scale3d(.97,.97,.97)}to{opacity:1;-webkit-transform:scaleX(1);transform:scaleX(1)}}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>This box should fade in and bounce on click</p>
  <div class="hud"></div>
</body>
```

Quick tip: with this method you can play as many animation as you want on the same element, just add its name to the .anim animations list and you're done!